# Поменять значения узлов на их высоты в бинарном дереве

Tags: java, алгоритм, бинарное-дерево, дерево

Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы в бинарном дереве поменять значения узлов на их высоты. По условию задания нужно поменять все значения за 1 проход дерева, но можно "выкрутиться", используя дополнительные структуры данных. У меня есть код, но не могу довести его до ума.

```
    public void replaceValuesToHeight() {
    replaceValuesToHeight(getRoot(), new Stack<>(), new Stack<>(), 0, 0, 0, true);
    }

    private int replaceValuesToHeight(TreeNode node, Stack<TreeNode> leftTree, Stack<TreeNode> rightTree, int level, int maxLeft, int maxRight, boolean isLeft) {
    if (maxLeft < level ) maxLeft = level;
    if (maxRight < level ) maxRight = level;

    if (level == 0 && isLeft) {
        leftTree.add(getRoot());
    }

    if (node.getLeft() != null) {
        leftTree.add(node.getLeft());
        maxLeft = replaceValuesToHeight(node.getLeft(), leftTree, rightTree, level + 1, maxLeft, maxRight, true);
    } 


    if (node.getRight() != null) {
        rightTree.add(node.getRight());
        maxRight = replaceValuesToHeight(node.getRight(), leftTree, rightTree, level + 1, maxLeft, maxRight, false);
    } 

    if (maxLeft < maxRight) {
        while (!leftTree.isEmpty()) {
            leftTree.pop().value = maxRight - level;
        }
        leftTree.add(getRoot());

    }

    if (maxRight < maxLeft) {
        while (!rightTree.isEmpty()) {
            rightTree.pop().value = maxLeft - level;
        }
        rightTree.add(getRoot());
    }
    node.value = Math.max(maxRight, maxLeft) - level;


    return isLeft ? maxLeft : maxRight;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы найти все "высоты" за один проход, нужно использовать [обход дерева в "обратном" порядке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0) - `postorder`

```
int postorder(node)
   if (node = null)
     return 0
   depth = 1 + max(postorder(node.left), postorder(node.right))
   node.value = depth   
   return depth
```

Comment: Я это понимаю, но реализовать алгоритм не получается

Comment: Ну вот псевдокод